# Qt/QSqlQuery: Error "No query Unable to fetch row"?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
QString qryTxt = "INSERT INTO payments_" + getCurrentYear() + " (" + current_month + ") VALUES (" + QString::number(1) + ") WHERE ref_no = " + refNosList[i];
query.prepare(qryTxt);
if (!query.exec())
{
     qDebug() << "Error" << query.lastError().text();
     return false;
}
```

in the debugging mode this what I see as my qryTxt:

```
"INSERT INTO payments_2015 (January) VALUES (1) WHERE ref_no = 3"
```

But it is still returning the following error:

```
Error "No query Unable to fetch row"
```

P.S.: without the part saying `WHERE ref_no = 3`, the query works fine.

**extra**

- The ref_no (3) exists in the db
- table and column names are correct

Comment: What do you want to do there? A `WHERE` clause is not allowed and does not make sense with `INSERT`.

Comment: @RobinKrahl Thanks for reply.  I want to add the number 1 to each row in that table in that month's column where the adjacent ref_no(s) equal specific ref_no(s) that exist in that array.

Comment: So you want to change existing rows? Use the `UPDATE` command: `UPDATE payments_2015 SET January = 1 WHERE ref_no = 3`.

Comment: Why are you manually building the SQL query string -- which is extremely dangerous -- and then calling `prepare()`? That makes very little sense.

Comment: @RobinKrahl .. it worked .. as you mentioned, I was trying to insert on already existing record instead of updating it that is why `WHERE` didn't work before .. thanks .. please put your comment as an answer to accept it ..

Comment: @MrEricSir .. You are absolutely right .. However, this way, i have more control over what to write on the query .. `QSqlQueryModel.setQuery` or  `QSqlQuery.prepare` are somehow limited in terms of flexibility writing the executed query. .. But, I promise you, I will change it later .. now I am just worried about the general functionalities in my app